# How to get the value of a dropdown list in angular without select/option

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get the value of a selected item from a dropdown list and send it to the input value, but without using select/option elements since it is hard to customize.

HTML

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ selectedInsurance }}">
<div ngbDropdown>
<button type="button" ngbDropdownToggle>check company</button>
<ul ngbDropdownMenu name="insurance" [(ngModel)]="selectedInsurance">
<li ngbDropdownItem *ngFor="let insurance of insurances">{{ insurance }}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

TS

```
selectedInsurance;
insurances: Array<string>  = ['AIA', 'Relliance', 'Other'];
```

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kt9e.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use click and manually set the values

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ selectedInsurance }}">
<div ngbDropdown>
<button type="button" ngbDropdownToggle>check company</button>
<ul ngbDropdownMenu name="insurance">
<li ngbDropdownItem (click)='selectedInsurance = insurance' *ngFor="let insurance of insurances">{{ insurance }}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```